# A problem showing "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" during runtime

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

During runtime, the app resets to a white screen and shows "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0" under SceneDelegate.swift. What could be the problem? Apologies if I'm missing anything in the post since I'm learning as I code. Thanks.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
@State private var countries = ["Estonia", "France", "Germany", "Ireland", "Italy", "Nigeria", "Poland", "Russia", "Spain", "UK", "US"].shuffled()
@State private var correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)

@State private var showingScore = false
@State private var scoreTitle = ""

var body: some View {

    ZStack {
        Color.blue.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            VStack {
                Text("Tap the flag of")
                foregroundColor(.white)

                Text(countries[correctAnswer])
                foregroundColor(.white)
            }

            ForEach(0 ..< 3) { number in
                Button(action: {
                   self.flagTapped(number)
                }) {
                    Image(self.countries[number])
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    .alert(isPresented: $showingScore) {
        Alert(title: Text(scoreTitle), message: Text("Your score is     ???"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Continue")) {
                self.askQuestion()
            })
        }
    }
func flagTapped(_ number: Int) {
    if number == correctAnswer {
        scoreTitle = "Correct"
    } else {
        scoreTitle = "Wrong"
    }

    showingScore = true
}

func askQuestion() {
    countries.shuffle()
    correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's really interesting unexpected coincidence issue, but here is fix

```
Text("Tap the flag of")
   .foregroundColor(.white)   // << use '.' (dot) before foregroundColor!!

Text(countries[correctAnswer])
   .foregroundColor(.white)   // << same !!
```